# mod_rewrite, rules overlapping

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, overlapping, internal-server-error

I'd like to make it so that when i enter http://website.com/5/sometitle it opens /displayvideo.php?id=5&title=sometitle, this currently works with the following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /displayvideo.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

However I'd also like to make it so that when i go to http://website.com/5 it will go to /displayvideo.php?id=5
I've tried this by adding

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /displayvideo.php?id=$1 [L]
```

however that just ends up with a bunch of weird crap like being unable to open actual files, like /somefile.php, as it will think the somefile.php should be an id tag by the rewriterule

Doing this also results of the other rewrite rule to become invalid because it automatically thinks /displayvideo.php?id=$1 is a tag of the new rule.

Basically every page on the site becomes a 500 internal server error

Anyone knows how to fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /displayvideo.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /displayvideo.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Refine your RegExp's:

```php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /displayvideo.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /displayvideo.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```